# Process running on sql server 2008 R2 with spid = -2

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008-r2

On a Sql Server 2008 R2 SP2, I'm unable to delete a database.
The error is: Database is in use.

Looking in activity monitor, I see nothing

Running DBCC OPENTRAN I see an active transaction with a SPID: 13s. That I'm unable to kill because of the 's' seems to be a sytem transaction.

Here is the result of command DBCC opentran:

`Oldest active transaction:
   SPID (server process ID): 35s
   UID (user ID) : -1
   Name          : offline index build
   LSN           : (4082851:348:145)
   Start time    : Jul 25 2014  4:06:51:260PM
   SID           : 0x0`

Content of syslockinfo lokk like this:

```
rsc_text                         rsc_bin                            rsc_valblk                         rsc_dbid rsc_indid rsc_objid   rsc_type rsc_flag req_mode req_status req_refcnt req_cryrefcnt req_lifetime req_spid    req_ecid    req_ownertype req_transactionID    req_transactionUOW
-------------------------------- ---------------------------------- ---------------------------------- -------- --------- ----------- -------- -------- -------- ---------- ---------- ------------- ------------ ----------- ----------- ------------- -------------------- ------------------------------------
                                 0x00000000000000000000000016000200 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 22       0         0           2        0        3        1          1          0             0            -2          0           4             0                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
                                 0x00000000000000000000000016000200 0x00000000000000000000000000000000 22       0         0           2        0        3        1          1          0             0            122         0           4             0                    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
```

If I do a backup and restore of that DB with other namre, I get the same problem. So I suppose it has something to do with uncommited transaction. Of course unable to shrink the log that keep growing and growing.

This problem seems to happen everytime we use a C# client application that uses Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo <-- This was a bad hypothesis !!!

In fact the source database from witch we take the backup already contains that trasaction with spid=-2. So it has nothing to doc with the C# client. 
The problems is **how can we get rid of that -2 transaction in the source database ?**

Any help to understand the problem would be great !

Thx,

Comment: Are you using transactions in your SMO-driven C# app? Are you closing and disposing transactions and connections properly?

Comment: I do not use explicit transaction and all connection are used in a using block. I also must say that everyting is running fine on sql 2005.

Comment: I think there is still a possibility of a connection remaining open even if it is within a using block, especially if something still needs to use the resource.

Comment: mungea05, can you give an exemple (May I remind you that the code works on SQL2005 without any problem). Could it be linked to a version of SMO library  ?

Comment: please add additional information to the question at this moment is difficult to figure out what the issue is. Code examples library version etc would be helpful or indication of what is being done on the smo app.

Comment: No specif code, just trying to backup, delete and restore database trough SMO.

Comment: I already moved on to SQL 2012 but if I remember correctly you can Detach the DB and check the Drop Connections

Answer (score 4):

SPID -2 is an orphaned DTC transaction.

You can find the info(UOW number or Unit of Work Number) about SPID-2 with the following query:

```
select req_transactionUOW
from master..syslockinfo
where req_spid = -2
```

You can not kill this sort of process with normally so you need the UOW id to do so.

The following command can be used to kill the process where the GUID number is the Unit of work ID found by the query above.

```
KILL 'C2645B98-2962-4c3e-83AC-8A5626A0C0A3'
```

Below is some interesting read about negative spid ids in sql server.

- http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/disaster-recovery-101-dealing-with-negative-spids-2-and-3/

I found this from this original post : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/c856fb4b-9c61-4180-a172-f6ceed5b0c45/blocking-caused-by-2-spid

There is some additional information there about the spid -2 which I have put below for your reading.

> The SPID is releated to MSDTC() when user fires transaction and that
>   transaction uses the data when the data as been replicated one or more
>   servers so MSDTC has to co-ordinate so this will take care by SQL db
>   engine. so during this type of an activity something went wrong like
>   any power outage on replicated server the MSDTC has to follow the ACID
>   rule how ever if MSDTC can't recover from this situation this and mark
>   that SPID to the Orpahned SPID hence you can see the SPID changes from
>   + to -ve number like -2(in this case).
>
> the reason why you are seeing block is due to it is still holding some
>   of the resources like it may be an page/row or any other object. so
>   obviuosly this will block other spids where other spids are trying to
>   access the same...
>
> so the Kill command will not work for -ve spid hence you have to
>   choose UNIT OF WORK(UOW) id for the spid then use the kill on  it.. 
>   note that you cant stop this type of an activity...
>   *From : Rama Udaya.K*

Comment: Hi,the OOW id is always guid empty. By the way the DTC Transaction UI doesn't show any information. I also tryed to stop the DTC services with no effect.

Comment: What does the syslockinfo table returns

Comment: Returns 2 rows. first one seems to be the connection I have with Sql Management studio. I had the second one above because it's more readable.

Comment: your c# application must be doing something incorrectly can you tell us what it does?

Comment: I made an update above. Problem seems already being present in the source database. So everytime we make a backup/restore we duplicate the problem. Question 1 is how can we remove that orphaned transaction, Question 2 is where did that problem come from (migration from 2005 --> 2008 ?)